# Would like to extend codeigniter inbuilt table function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am dealing with table's using codeigniter's inbuilt function, currently I have an object with data that would be of 3 columns, which can directly be passed to

```
echo $this->table->generate($obj);
```

to generate the table. However I would like to extend this structure and have 4 columns.
The output is:

```
Id   Title          Description 

2   fdgdgdf         sdfsfsfs
3   fsdfsdf         sdfsfsdfsf
```

I would like it to be

```
Id   Title          Description    Action

2   fdgdgdf         sdfsfsfs         edit
3   fsdfsdf         sdfsfsdfsf       edit
```

Moreover, is there a way via which I can use the id... for the action edit (which is a hyperlink).
Or is it the best to go for the conventional way i.e. plain PHP for loops?

Answer (score 0):

First thing - add a field to the header:

```
$this->table->set_heading('Id', 'Title', 'Description', 'Action');
```

Next - just form the $obj[3] or last column like that:

```
$obj[3] = '<a href=".../'.$obj[0].'"></a>';
```